# Selector unknown returned the root state when called. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders (warning)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, useselector

When I try to go to another user's profile page I get an endless warning in console and I don't get the page and there is nothing else to do on the page so I have to close it and open new tap again.

[image]

profileAction.js

```
import { GLOBALTYPES } from "./globalTypes";
import { getDataAPI } from "../../utils/fetchData";

export const PROFILE_TYPES = {
    LOADING: 'LOADING',
    GET_USER: 'GET_USER'
}


export const getProfileUsers = ({users, id, auth}) => async (dispatch) => {
    if(users.every(user => user._id !== id)){
        
        try {
            dispatch({type: PROFILE_TYPES.LOADING, payload: true})
            const res = await getDataAPI(`/user/${id}`, auth.token)
            console.log(res)

        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: GLOBALTYPES.ALERT, 
                payload: {error: err.response.data.msg}
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Info.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Avatar from '../Avatar';
import { getProfileUsers } from '../../redux/actions/profileAction';

const Info = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { auth, profile } = useSelector(state => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(id === auth.user._id){
      setUserData(auth.user)
      // console.log(userData)
    }else{
      dispatch(getProfileUsers({users: profile.users, id, auth}))
    }
  }, [id, auth.user, profile.users])

  const followed = userData.followers || []

  const follow = userData.following || []
  
  return (
        <div className='info'>
        {userData ? 
          <div className="info_container" key={userData._id}>
            <Avatar src={userData.avatar} size="supper-avatar"/>
            <div className="info_content">
              <div className="info_content_title">
                <h2>{userData.username}</h2>
                <button className="btn btn-outline-info">
                  Edit Profile
                </button>
              </div>
                <div className="follow_btn">
                  <span className="mr-4">
                    {followed.length} Followers
                  </span>
                  <span className="ml-4">
                    {follow.length} Following
                  </span>
                </div>
              <h6>{userData.fullname}</h6>
              <h6>{userData.email}</h6>
            </div>
          </div> : null
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Info
```

By the way, I always get this warning before, but the pages were working fine and the warning was not endless

Comment: I think, as per docs `state` returned from `useSelector` (from your code of `state => state`) is in general the entire state present in the store which we would probably not wanted to fetch. If its the only data present in store then redux is not the right tool IMO. I feel the warning can be ignored if its the only state and still you wanted to use redux.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you are selecting "too much state", in this case you are subscribing to ***all*** state. In other words, any time ***any*** state is updated, regardless if it is related to what is destructured/used in `Info`, the `Info` component will be triggered to rerender.

The solution is to narrow the scope of what you are selecting.

```js
const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth);
const profile = useSelector(state => state.profile);
```

This will trigger `Info` to rerender when any of the `auth` or `profile` state value changes, but not other state.

Based on the code that `Info` actually references, the scope can be narrowed further still.

```js
const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);
const users = useSelector(state => state.profile.users);
```

Now this should only trigger a component rerender when specifically the `user` or `users` states update.

The render looping issues are likely related this `useEffect` hook call. It is a bit of a React anti-pattern to duplicate passed/selected values/"derived state" into local state. The `userData` value should be computed directly from the current `id` and `user` values. Just about any time you find that you have coded a `useState`/`useEffect` coupling you should really use the `useMemo` hook to compute (*and memoize*) a stable reference value.

```js
const { id } = useParams();
const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);

const userData = useMemo(() => {
  return id === user._id ? user : null;
}, [id, user]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (id !== userData._id) {
    dispatch(getProfileUsers({ id }));
  }
}, [id, userData]);
```

This could be further improved by returning the computed user data directly in the `useSelector` hook.

```js
const { id } = useParams();
const user = useSelector(state => {
  return id === user._id ? state.auth.user : null;
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (!user) {
    dispatch(getProfileUsers({ id }));
  }
}, [id, user]);
```

Update the `getProfileUsers` action to consume only an `id` argument and use the Thunk's `getState` function to access the store value. This removes the other external dependencies.

```js
export const getProfileUsers = ({ id }) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const state = getState();
  const { auth, profile: { users } } = state;

  if (users.every(user => user._id !== id)) {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: PROFILE_TYPES.LOADING, payload: true });
      const res = await getDataAPI(`/user/${id}`, auth.token);
      console.log(res);

    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: GLOBALTYPES.ALERT, 
        payload: { error: err.response.data.msg }
      });
    } finally {
      dispatch({ type: PROFILE_TYPES.LOADING, payload: false });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that when I go to another user’s profile, as soon as I refresh the page, the infinite rerendering occurs.

Comment: @PhoenixPhoenix Why are you duplicating the user data into local state? The `useEffect` appears to create a render loop when setting the `userData` state while `id` is equal to `auth.user._id`.